How does the size of a resistor affect its power usage?
I'm trying to buy an electric stove and am a bit confused. There are two options: 500W and 1000W. They are very basic: just a circuit with a switch (controlled by a thermostat which is adjusted by the knob) and a resistor (the heating element.) All the materials appear to be same between the models. As far as I can tell, the only difference between them is the size of the heating element, the 1000W model being larger.
According to P = V²/R, power dissipation decreases with increased resistance.
I must have something back-to-front, because I would have imagined that the larger heating element would have more resistance due to its size, but according to the maths, this would result in less power consumption.
Where am I going wrong?

An intuitive answer:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. a) A single cooker element. b) Two in parallel.

In figure 1a we have a single cooker element. It has a certain resistance and let's say it's power rating is 500 W.
In figure 1b we have two of the same cooker elements in parallel. Each is 500 W. If we now combine them in the same element package we have a 1000 W heater and clearly the elements are still in parallel and the resistance (to current flow) has halved.

Yes, the resistance has been halved but the current will double. If we use the alternative power equation P = I2R we can see that while the smaller R value has a halving effect on P, the doubling of the current has a × 22 effect on P. The result is a doubling of power.

Notes:

The 1000 W element could be made with two 500 W heating wires in parallel internally or just one wire of twice the cross-sectional area.
A technical point: these hobs don't have "thermostats" which will cut out at a certain temperature. Instead they have power controllers which switch the element on and off periodically with more and more on-time as you increase the setting. They have no idea and no control of the temperature. (It's a bit like a car's accelerator does not set the speed but it controls the engine power output.)

Further reading: Setting heat on electric stove.

You're right, the cooker has one of those thermomechanical hobs. If I understand your link correctly, the bimetallic strip is heated by the power source, not by the air surrounding it. So you can't get the hob to stay on by ventilating the base of the stove, for example.

Hmm, I'm not sure what's normally done. The simplest would be to run current through the bimetallic strip to heat it and cause it to open but that would give a control rate dependent on the hob element size. (They'd want a standard part for all sizes.)  The other option is to have a fine heater wire connected between N and switched L wrapped around or close to the bimetallic strip. This would continue to switch even if the load was disconnected.

I think the space between the bimetallic strip and the switch can be varied to change the control rate.

That's effectively what the control knob does. There's a cam driven by the knob to increase the gap. In the photo in the linked answer there seems to be an adjustment screw as well.

The higher power unit is manufactured in a different way to make it higher power, probably  such that the power per unit area is roughly constant. This is a fundamental metric for heaters.
While it's true at some level that if the two heaters were manufactured of exactly the same resistance wire you'd need less length to make the higher power heater, from the textbook \$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}\$ that's generally not going to give a desirable result for other reasons. If all that heat is concentrated into the same area and there is half the length of wire, then the surface may get too hot and the wire may fail prematurely.
So the heater manufacturer will use a larger diameter wire or perhaps two wires in parallel and likely use (in total) more length of it to cover a larger area. That allows it to get rid of the heat (hopefully much of it will be transmitted to whatever is being cooked).
A similar principle applies to resistors. Consider the Yageo leaded series:

The 3W MFR2WS has a body surface area of πDL = 243\$\text {mm}^2\$
The 2W MFR3WS has a body surface area of πDL = 163\$\text {mm}^2\$ or 2/3 of that of the MFR200.
This is true regardless of the resistor value. The metal film composition, thickness and geometry over the surface of the cylinder is varied so that the desired resistance can be achieved without the film being too thin or the spiral too narrow.
Surface area (all other things being equal) is related to power capability rather than usage. The heater designer will manipulate the variables under their control to make the heater capable of 500W or 1000W and to actually draw that much power.

The MFR200 is rated for 2 W, not 3 W. The MFR3WS, which has the same external dimensions, is the 3 W one. Likewise, the MFR100 is rated for 1 W, but the same-size MFR2WS is rated for 2 W.  I can only assume the "miniature" series has some kind of different construction that lets it handle a little more power in the same package.

Okay, so since R=ρL/A and P=V²/R, we can say P=V²A/pL, right?

@RogerKeays Yes, for a bar of material of length L and cross-sectional area A with contacts at either end and resistivity $\rho$.

@Hearth Thanks, I'll edit the correct miniature part numbers in. Handle more power mostly means it runs hotter, though maybe the leads are different (copper instead of steel, perhaps).

Transistor's answer deserves the tick, but I want to point out that if you increase resistance, while keeping voltage the same, you reduce current, according to Ohm's law:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R} $$
Consider that power is the product of the voltage \$V\$ across the element, and the current \$I\$ through it:
$$ P = I \times V $$
Clearly, power depends on both current and voltage, and by changing resistance you are changing current also. You can't then make the claim that "power goes up (or down) with  resistance". Sure, if current remained unchanged, then such a statement may be true, but current is not constant.

Combining the other answers in this thread, we have P=V²/R and R=ρL/A, which gives us P=V²A/ρL. So both increasing a resistor's cross-sectional area and decreasing its length will increase power usage for a given voltage.
P = power
V = electrical potential difference
R = resistance
ρ = resistivity of the resistor
L = length of the resistor
A = cross-sectional area of the resistor

